# Odoo - load a form view from new button in tree header

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, odoo-10

I created two new buttons in JS and replaced the original Add button in tree view of a model:

```
ListView.include({
        render_buttons: function() {
            var self = this;            
            this._super.apply(this, arguments)
            if (this.model=='account.cash'){
            if (this.$buttons) {
                this.$buttons.find('.o_list_button_income').on('click', this.proxy('do_new_income'))
                this.$buttons.find('.o_list_button_add').css({"display":"none"})
            }
            }
        },   

        do_new_income: function () {

            var model = new Model('account.cash');
            var self = this;        
            model.call('new_income', [[]])
```

With this button I´m trying to call a form view by following method:

```
    @api.model
    def new_income(self):
        view_id = self.env.ref('account.view_cash_statement_form').id
        context = self._context.copy()
        return {
            'name': 'New income',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'views': [(view_id, 'form')],
            'res_model': 'account.cash',
            'context': context,
            'target': 'current',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window'
        }
```

However this is not working. When I try to call this method as a test in other view from button defined in standard XML view definition, it is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.call('new_income', [[]]).then(function (res) { self.do_action(res)})`

where res is the returned value from python did the trick